# Parent div gets longer when child gets longer

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a calendar to the left and a side bar to the right:
[image]

The problem is that, cases are overflowing. Instead, I need to show a scrollbar when it gets longer than its parent.

They are in bootstrap accordions.

Here is the html:

```
 <div id="cal-container">
        <div id="cal-side">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle project-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#project-list">Projects
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="project-list" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                            <div class="event-container project-container">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle task-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#task-list">Tasks
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="task-list" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                            <div class="event-container task-container">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-group">
                    <div class="accordion-heading">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle case-header" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#case-list">Cases
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="case-list" class="accordion-body collapse">
                        <div class="accordion-inner">
                            <div class="event-container case-container">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="cal">
            <div id='calendar'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The events go into the event-containers.

This is the CSS:

```
#cal-side
{
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    width:200px;
    margin:50px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#cal-container
{
    width:100%;
}

.accordion-inner
{
    padding:2px 2px !important;
}

.external-event { /* try to mimick the look of a real event */
    margin: 2px;
    padding-left:4px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:blue;
    font-size: .85em;
    cursor: pointer;    
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }

.event-container
{
    margin:1px;
}
#cal{ 
}
```

Here is some generated html:
[image]

I have tried several types of overflow:auto. The only thing that 'worked' was setting event-container max-height to a fixed pixel ammount. Then I see a scrollbar for cases, but otherwise, it does what you see. I need the max height to be the height of cal-side or something...

I'm not sure what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your container, set a `max-height` and put `overflow: auto`

**Working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/DRVMG/13/

**EDIT** The below code is only to satisfy a comment the OP made below, I'm not suggesting `jQuery` to his original post:

To set the calendar's height to the height of the sidebar, you would do:

```
$("#sidebar-id").css({"max-height" : $("#calendar-id").height() });
```

And then in CSS you would need to set the `overflow` of the `sidebar div` to `auto`

Comment: But the max height has to be less than the max height of #cal-container. Also, which container?

Comment: The problem is all your numbers are absolute... #cal-container's height is determined by the calendar and is not fixed... I need cal-side's max-height to be the height of the calendar I guess somehow...

Comment: @Milo Well think about what you're saying, if the container (cal-container) doesn't have a `max-height` - how would the browser know to stop it from expanding?

Comment: @Milo And why would you want the `max-height` of the sidebar to be the height of the calendar? I thought that is what you were trying to *avoid*

Comment: @Milo Now I understand, you can simply use jQuery to do that ;)

Comment: Okay, could you give me a JQuery example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27865/discussion-between-evan-and-milo)

Answer (score 0):

Setting overflow doesn't change the way in which an element expands to contain its children.  As you seem to have already noticed, you need to combine the overflow setting of your choice (e.g., `auto`) *with* a specific height.

Have you tried a height of 100% on `.event-container`?  It's hard to tell without playing around with it, but that might give the desired behavior (depends on what you having going on further up the DOM tree, though).